# Rings of Cosets: Consider the ideal $\langle x^2 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the ideal $\langle x^2 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Prove that for each $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, there exists $a+bx\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, so that $\langle x^2 \rangle +f=\langle x^2 \rangle+(a+bx)$.

---

Since $\langle x^2 \rangle$ is the ideal,  $x^2 =0$.

So, $\langle x^2 \rangle +f=0+f=f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ where $\deg(f)<2=a+bx$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$

---

I'm not sure if this is all I need to show.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really proved anything. The idea is to find, given $f = a_dx^d+\dots+a_1x+a_0 \in \Bbb Q[x]$, a polynomial $a+bx \in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $f$ and $a+bx$ are equivalent in $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$. **Hint**: in the quotient $x^2=0$, thus $x^3=xx^2=0$, $x^4=0$, etc.